# How to open the last file of a folder in a SharePoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to ask help on creating commands which will be able to open ONLY the latest file of a folder in a SharePoint using VBA. Your prompt response is greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the shell command Dir (not the VBA command dir) you can sort the files according to date ( /o-d ) . If you use a descending sort the first file will be the most recent.

```
Sub M_snb()
  msgbox split(createobject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir G:\OF\*.* /b /o-d").stdout.readall,vbcrlf)(0)
End Sub
```